# meteor.js Ostrio:files: Viewing files with the package ” aslagle : reactive -table ”

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Hi does anyone have experience using the package " aslagle : reactive - table" to display files recorded with the package "ostrio:files" in the data collection.
here's my code:

```
File .html:
<template name="images">
{{> reactiveTable collection=images fields=fields settings=settings class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed"}}
</template>

File .js:
Template.images.onCreated( () => {
  Template.instance().subscribe( 'files.images.all' );
});

Template.images.helpers({
  images: function () {
    return Images.find();
  },

  settings: function() {
        return {
            rowsPerPage: 20,
            showFilter: true,
            fields: [
            {
                key: 'file.name',
                label: 'Images'
            },
          ]
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
Template.images.helpers({
  Images: function () {
    return Images.find().fetch();
  },
settings: function() {
        return {
            rowsPerPage: 20,
            showFilter: true,

            fields: [
            {key: 'link', label: 'link', tmpl: Template._link},
          ]
        };
    }
});

<template name="_link">
    <a href="{{_downloadRoute}}/{{_collectionName}}/{{_id}}/original/{{_id}}{{extension}}?download=true" download="{{name}}">{{name}}</a>
</template>
```